# ASP.MVC CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider not maintaining additional values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a modified `MetadataProvider` based on the `CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`.  Within my custom metadata, I provide data into the additional values dictionary. When I look at the cache from within the provider, it is populated correctly with `ModelMetadata` objects and those objects are properly populated with the additional values.

Within my custom provider, I am overriding:

```
CreateMetadataPrototype(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Type modelType, string propertyName)
```

and I am setting values within the provider through the add method on the dictionary.

However, when I access the `ModelMetadata` from a View, the additional data is no longer populated.

Other properties in the `ModelMetadata` are populated, but the additional data dictionary is not.

If I switch the custom metadataprovider to use the standard `DataAnnotations` metadata provider instead of the caching provider, the additional values are properly populated.

When I drill down into the MVC code, it appears as though the method

```
CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadata CreateMetadataFromPrototype(CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadata prototype, Func<object> modelAccessor)
```

does not fully populate the return CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadata object.

I fix this by overriding the method, but this seems a bit strange and leads me to believe I am using the Cached provider incorrectly.

So is there a different prefered way to handle `ModelMetadata` in the cached provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `CreateMetadataFromPrototype()` insted of `CreateMetadataPrototype()`